# how to make textarea displaying

Tags: java, textarea

I have a project to help the teacher in his work. This part shows the text area, then it disappeared like for a microsecond. I tried it alone with a frame and all the stuff but when it's a function and I call it seems like I have an error.
In my code, there are a lot of functions that call each other.

```
public JLabel ajtsjt() {
    JLabel p=new JLabel();

    p.setBounds(0, 0, 1200, 700);
    ImageIcon icon44=new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop\\3eme\\S2\\PROJET\\icons\\home.png");
    ImageIcon icon4=new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop\\3eme\\S2\\PROJET\\icons\\home1.png");
    ImageIcon icon33=new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop\\3eme\\S2\\PROJET\\icons\\yes.png");
    ImageIcon icon3=new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop\\3eme\\S2\\PROJET\\icons\\yes1.png");
    JButton yes=new JButton(icon3);
    yes.setBounds(850,550, 100, 100);
    yes.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    yes.setBorderPainted(false);
    
    p.add(yes);
    
    yes.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
        
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
        
        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            yes.setIcon(icon3);
        }
        
        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            yes.setIcon(icon33);
        }
        
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            yes.setIcon(icon3);
        }
    });
    
    yes.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            anime.jLabelYDown(p.getY(), 1000,1, 3, p);
            lblNewLabel_3.add(sjt());
            lblNewLabel_3.remove(ajtsjt());
        }
    });
    
    JButton home=new JButton(icon4);
    home.setBounds(1000,550, 100, 100);
    home.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    home.setBorderPainted(false);
    
    p.add(home);
    
    home.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
        
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
        
        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            home.setIcon(icon4);
        }
        
        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            home.setIcon(icon44);
        }
        
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            home.setIcon(icon4);
        }
    });
    
    home.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            anime.jLabelYDown(p.getY(), 1000,1, 3, p);
            lblNewLabel_3.add(sjt());
            lblNewLabel_3.remove(ajtsjt());
        }
    });
    
    JLabel titre=new JLabel("Titre");
    titre.setBounds(25, 25, 200, 25);
    titre.setFont(font3);
    p.add(titre);
    titre.setForeground(Color.white);
    
    JLabel domaine=new JLabel("Domaine");
    domaine.setBounds(25, 75, 200, 25);
    domaine.setFont(font3);
    p.add(domaine);
    domaine.setForeground(Color.white);
    
    JLabel mot_cles=new JLabel("Mot clés");
    mot_cles.setBounds(25, 125, 200, 25);
    mot_cles.setFont(font3);
    p.add(mot_cles);
    mot_cles.setForeground(Color.white);
    
    JLabel obj_et_dem=new JLabel("Objectif et démarche");
    obj_et_dem.setBounds(25, 175, 200,50);
    obj_et_dem.setFont(font3);
    p.add(obj_et_dem);
    obj_et_dem.setForeground(Color.white);
    
    JLabel out_et_meth=new JLabel("Outils et méthodes");
    out_et_meth.setBounds(25, 250, 200, 50);
    out_et_meth.setFont(font3);
    p.add(out_et_meth);
    out_et_meth.setForeground(Color.white);

    JLabel fon_att=new JLabel("<html>Fonctionnalités<br> attendus</html>");
    fon_att.setBounds(25, 325, 0200,150);
    fon_att.setFont(font3);
    p.add(fon_att);
    fon_att.setForeground(Color.white);
    
    JLabel eta_a_sui=new JLabel("Etapes à suivre");
    eta_a_sui.setBounds(25, 500, 0200, 50);
    eta_a_sui.setFont(font3);
    p.add(eta_a_sui);
    eta_a_sui.setForeground(Color.white);
    
    JTextArea ttitre=new JTextArea();
    ttitre.setBounds(250, 25, 0600, 25);
    p.add(ttitre);
    ttitre.setFont(font2);
    ttitre.setForeground(Color.blue);
    
    JTextArea tdomaine=new JTextArea();
    tdomaine.setBounds(250, 75, 0600, 25);
    p.add(tdomaine);
    tdomaine.setFont(font2);
    tdomaine.setForeground(Color.blue);
    
    JTextArea tmot_cles=new JTextArea();
    tmot_cles.setBounds(250, 125, 0600, 25);
    p.add(tmot_cles);
    tmot_cles.setFont(font2);
    tmot_cles.setForeground(Color.blue);
    
    TextArea tobj_et_dem=new TextArea();
    tobj_et_dem.setBounds(250, 175, 0600, 50);
    p.add(tobj_et_dem);
    tobj_et_dem.setFont(font2);
    tobj_et_dem.setForeground(Color.blue);
    
    TextArea tout_et_meth=new TextArea();
    tout_et_meth.setBounds(250, 250, 0600, 50);
    p.add(tout_et_meth);
    tout_et_meth.setFont(font2);
    tout_et_meth.setForeground(Color.blue);
    
    TextArea ttfon_att=new TextArea();
    ttfon_att.setBounds(250, 325, 0600, 150);
    p.add(ttfon_att);
    ttfon_att.setFont(font2);
    ttfon_att.setForeground(Color.blue);
    
    TextArea tata_a_sui=new TextArea();
    tata_a_sui.setBounds(250, 500, 0600, 50);
    p.add(tata_a_sui);
    tata_a_sui.setFont(font2);
    tata_a_sui.setForeground(Color.blue);
    return p;
}
```

Comment: I can't get the code to run. Can you post the rest of the code please?

Comment: Don't use TextArea. That is an AWT component. For Swing your should be using a `JTextArea`. Don't use a null layout. Don't use setBounds(). Swing was designed to be used with layout managers.

Comment: thanx guys I found the solution; the problem was in the layout: I used this one "ScrollPaneLayout". thank you again